# Changing cardinality of existing relationship class in enterprise geodatabase?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, relationship-class

Is it possible to change the cardinality of an existing relationship class in enterprise geodatabase?

I want to alter a 1-m relationship class to m-m

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately, it is impossible to modify the cardinality of an existing relationship class in any geodatabase.

From the [Viewing and modifying relationship properties](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/relationships/viewing-and-modifying-relationship-properties-abou.htm) documentation:

> You can't modify any of the properties you specified when you created
>   the relationship class except for renaming it. You can set and change
>   relationship rules at your discretion. If you need to change other
>   properties, it is easy to delete the relationship class and re-create
>   it.